# I tried to add a slider from W3schools but the pictures are upside down and no errors shown in console

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

```
<?php
require_once "connection.php";
require_once "regulator.php";
?>
<html>
    <head>  
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "slider.css">
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "bootstrap.min.css">  
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
          <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
          <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">   </li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                  <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">

                  <div class="item active">
                    <img src="img/img_download/pic1.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
                      <p>LA is always so much fun!</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/img_download/pic2.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h3>Chicago</h3>
                      <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                
                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/img_download/pic3.jpg" alt="New York" style="width:100%;">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h3>New York</h3>
                      <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>  
            </div>
            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <script src = "slider.js"></script>
                <script src = "Jquery.js"></script>
        <script src = "bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

I added the code from from W3schools official page ("Bootstrap Carousel Plugin"), downloaded and connected bootstrap.min.css, ...js and Jquery, but the pictures are just upside down with roll left or right option(text on the last pic at the bottom), no errors shown in console. Just can't figure out what could be the reason?